# Is it a good thing to use label / text to verify that element is found on the current page?

Tags: selenium, xpath, robotframework, selector

I'm new with robot framework so my qst is :
in order to verify if a field exists on a page,is it good to use the field label  for that :

```
${element_to_test}    //label[contains(text(),'test1, test2, test3')]
```

NB / I got this xpath by using chropath tool after selecting the target field
thanks guys

Comment: It depends, if you text is fixed and not going to change then you can use text else using testid is always preferable approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the best selector since the test will fail when the text changes.
Best is to use a `testid` for interacting with elements.

See:
https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices#Selecting-Elements

(Written for Cypress, but locating strategies are basically the same between all frameworks)